# Why ! is used before pip command?

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, kaggle

I worked on a dataset in Kaggle and I see that in some python notebooks, they have used ! before pip command for installing packages.

For example: **!pip install rank_bm25 nltk**

Is there any reason behind it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kaggle, but in a lot of applications which provide an interactive console, `!` is used to run an external *shell command*.

Comment: Kaggle uses Jupyter notebook format. You can run Command Line Codes by using the Exclamation mark " ! " before the codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some python interactive shells like ipython or kaggle `!` is prefixed to run external shell command.